# Determining the address of the file in the mmc (sd-card)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sd-card

I am trying to put splash screen image on my linux device, i want to read the image from mmc (sd-card). I need to locate the image address on the mmc (sd-card). for example "80a00000".

Is there any way to locate the address of a file in the mmc (sd-card) ?

Comment: I think you are looking for `ls -i`

Comment: is the index number and the memory address are the same ?